# Can't add attachment when creating Event with GraphServiceClient

Tags: c#-4.0, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create online teams meeting with attachments using Events with GraphServiceClient. I am able to create online meeting if I don't supply attachments but I get below error when supplying attachments.

```
ServiceException: 
Code: ErrorAttachmentsNotSupported
Message: Attachments are not supported.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: cb69967c-3c63-4b04-b232-333d540a51c6
    date: 2020-06-03T10:14:42
ClientRequestId: cb69967c-3c63-4b04-b232-333d540a51c6
```

Below is the code

```
        string OrgnizerUserIdTemp = "userid";

        var aAttachments = new EventAttachmentsCollectionPage();
        byte[] contentbytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\test.pdf");

        aAttachments.Add(new FileAttachment
        {
            Name = "Test.pdf",
            ContentBytes = contentbytes,
            ContentType = "application/pdf",
            ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            Size = contentbytes.Length
        });

        var @event = new Event
        {
            Subject = "Online Meeting for Teams",
            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                Content = "Some body content text here?<BR /> <B>Some Bold Text </B>"
            },
            Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
            {
                DateTime = "2020-06-03T12:00:00",
                TimeZone = "Europe/London"
            },
            End = new DateTimeTimeZone
            {
                DateTime = "2020-06-03T14:00:00",
                TimeZone = "Europe/London"
            },
            Location = new Location
            {
                DisplayName = "Lunch by Heston Blumenthal"
            },
            Attendees = new List<Attendee>()
            {
                new Attendee
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "AdeleV@sanjayksaxena.onmicrosoft.com",
                        Name = "Adele Vance"
                    },
                    Type = AttendeeType.Required
                },
                new Attendee
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "sanjay.saxena@sanjayksaxena.onmicrosoft.com",
                        Name = "Sanjay Saxena"
                    },
                    Type = AttendeeType.Required
                },
                new Attendee
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "user2@gmail.com",
                        Name = "User 2"
                    },
                    Type = AttendeeType.Optional
                }
            },
            IsOnlineMeeting = true,
            AllowNewTimeProposals = true,
            TransactionId = "7E163156-7762-4BEB-A1C6-729EA81755A1",
            Attachments = aAttachments, 
            HasAttachments = true
        };

        var om = graphServiceClient.Users[OrgnizerUserIdTemp].Events
            .Request()
            .Header("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"Europe/London\"")
            .AddAsync(@event).Result;
```

Is there any way to add attachments to events?
Or
if there is any other way to create Teams online meetings with attachments. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[onlineMeeting resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-beta) does not support adding attachments.
But you could create a calendar event with attachments and it has some limitations.
Please find the below link on how to add attachment to a calendar event [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-beta).

Limitations on Calendar Attachment :
You can add attachment objects to events in only user calendars, but not to events in group calendars.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I am pretty new to Microsoft Graph. Could you please tell what the difference between user calendar and group calendars? Or, please share a article.

Comment: Start with the api docs from microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0).
Under the calendar section you can see calendar,calendar group,events api which will walk you through the apis and request bodies. @SanjaySaxena